# Using _ViewStart to render partial razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an asp.net core project with the layout page:

```
_Layout.cshtml
```

Which is the default asp.net core _Layout page. No model involved.

In the `Areas` folder I have a couple of files:

```
Vendor > Pages > _ViewStart.cshtml
Vendor > Pages > _Menu.cshtml
Vendor > Pages > Index.cshtml
```

These files look like this:

**_ViewStart**

```
@{
    Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_Menu"); }
```

**_Menu**

```
@page
@model MyProject.Areas.Vendor.Pages.MenuModel
@{
    foreach(var i in Model.MenuItems)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink(i.DisplayText,i.Url)
    }
}
```

**Index**

```
@page
@model MyProject.Areas.Vendor.Pages.IndexModel
@{
}

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
```

Now I want to visit the `Vendor` index Razor page, but I want it to also render the `_Menu` options first, hence the `_ViewStart` with the `_Layout` and also the `_Menu` - basically every Vendor page I visit should have the `_Menu` rendered first.

But when I visit Index I get this error:

```
The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'MyProject.Areas.Vendor.Pages.IndexModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'MyProject.Areas.Vendor.Pages.MenuModel'
```

How can this be? I'm not passing anything to the `Index` page? And when I tried to specify `null` as an argument on `RenderPartialAsync()` I just get `null reference exception` on my _Menu page.

How can I achieve what I need?

It should render _Layout > _ViewStart > _Menu > AnyOtherVendorPage

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working demo like below:

1.Partial view should be razor view instead of razor pages:

```
@model List<YourProject.Models.MenuItem>
@{
    foreach (var i in Model)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink(i.DisplayText, i.Url)
    }
}
```

2._ViewStart.cshtml:

```
@{
    Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    var model = new List<YourProject.Models.MenuItem>()
    {
        new YourProject.Models.MenuItem(){ DisplayText="aaa", Url="aaa" },
        new YourProject.Models.MenuItem(){ DisplayText="bbb", Url="bbb" },
    };
}

@{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_Menu", model); }
```

Comment: I didn't want to have to supply a model, it was only ever going to use `IdentityUser` in the razor page, which in other pages I see was being supplied from `services` - in any case I ended up using a `ViewComponent` as recommended by the MSDN on any partial that would use code.